# How to define a general input constant in android studio?

Tags: java, android

I simply want that every time a user enter π it is defined as the number of Math.PI. I will further explain.

I have one edit text and another. I want if the users enter π in the text box the program will read it as 3.14 in every EditText in the method. So if I have two edit text i want the answer of the multiplication between the two doubles resulted. Per example in EditText 1 I have π and in EditText 2 I have 2 the answer would be 6.26.

Comment: First tell me, how will you enter the symbol, "π " on Android ?. The standard keypad doesn't support it. You need a custom keypad for that.

Comment: look at the comment from Pulp_fiction, you should put such a constants in  a dropdown and use a dictionary to llink the symbols to the numeric constants,

Comment: Yes I made a custom keypad for it. How could I do such a dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to handle this by yourself and use String.replace

```
String result = EDITTEXT.getText().toString().replace("π", "3.14");
```

This will replace all occurrences of pi with 3.14

Ofcourse you have to parse the String to an int after

```
float number = Float.parseFloat(result);
```

Comment: You mean Float.parseFloat:)

Comment: Thanks a lot,it works out for what I need for now, but if it could be done to all the Edittexts in my application without needing to write this code every time it would be great. But if there is no way that's fine at least it worked!

Comment: For that you could make your custom edittext which extends the normal edittext and override the getText()